# StreamBuilder always returning false in print(snapshot.hasData) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

i will showing message from firebase firestore in flutter , but when i make conditional in snapshot always returning false
this is my code

**Service**

```
Stream<List<MessageModel>> getMessagesByUserid({int userId}) {
    try {
      return firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
          .snapshots()
          .map((QuerySnapshot list) {
        var result = list.docs.map<MessageModel>((DocumentSnapshot message) {
          print('from service : ' + message.data().toString());
          return MessageModel.fromJson(message.data());
        }).toList();

        result.sort(
          (MessageModel a, MessageModel b) =>
              a.createdAt.compareTo(b.createdAt),
        );
        return result;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

and call with this

```
 Widget content() {
      return StreamBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
          stream: MessageService()
              .getMessagesByUserid(userId: authprovider.user.id),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.hasData);
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: defaultMargin,
                ),
                children: snapshot.data
                    .map(
                      (MessageModel message) => ChatBubble(
                        isSender: message.isFromUser,
                        text: message.message,
                        product: message.product,
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          });
    }
```

when i print in service , i get

```
I/flutter (29881): from service : {createdAt: 2021-06-28 16:29:25.106709, product: {}, userImage: https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=eka&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF, isFromUser: true, message: tanpa, userName: eka, userId: 2, updatedAt: 2021-06-28 16:29:25.106811}
```

but when i print(snapshot.hasData) always returning false

```
I/flutter (29881): false
```

Comment: Change `Stream` to `Future` in Services

Comment: You code might for getMessagesByUserid might be throwing and error.....

So return something in catch block as well to seee

Comment: Check `snapshot.connectionState'`rather than `snapshot.hasData`. The connectionState can be waiting, none, active or done and `hasData` can still be `false` is the `Stream` is returning `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you require more granularity when using `StreamBuilder` then test `snapshot.connectionState` rather than `snapshot.hasData`.

`snapshot.hasData` can still be false if the Stream is returning null